# how to pass a value to a "subvariable" with pandoc?

Tags: command-line-interface, pandoc

My `yaml`-file has these variables:

```
values:
- name: MyName
  amount: 123
---
```

In the pandoc-template for LaTeX I have inserted the variables as following:

```
$for(values)$
$if(values.name)$Name: $values.name$$endif$
$if(values.amount)$Amnount: $values.amount$$endif$
$endfor$
```

As long as I do a plain conversion with pandoc it works well.

But when I try to pass a value to the variable `values.amount` via the command line (from a makefile) it is not recognized however the subshell works fine.

```
pandoc --variable values.amount="$(shell awk 'NR>1{print $0}' myfile.csv | wc -l)" dummy.md -o final.pdf
```

> How do I pass a value to the variable `amount` via CLI?